# Make Star Schema Benchmark(SSB) on Windows

Tags: c++, benchmarking, nmake, star-schema

I'm trying to compile the star schema benchmark on windows, but it returns the following error.

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'dss.h'
```

I´m very noob on c++ and make. Can´t figure how to solve this.

Comment: I expect this means the header `dss.h` is not found.

Comment: Seems like you are missing ssb-dbgen.